# How can I check if atleast 2 checkboxes are checked in php?

Tags: php

I need to have php validation that says at least 2 checkboxes should be checked...
I have been trying different things but unable to get the right results.

```
    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['opt'])) {
        foreach($_POST['opt'] as $check) {
                echo $check; 

        }
    $checkboxes = count($check); 
    echo '$checkboxes'; 

    }
    ?>       

    <form action="index.php" method="post">

    <input type="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="option1" />option1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="option2" />option2<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="option3" />option3<br />


    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Your `count()` is outside of the scope of `$check`s use; try `count($_POST['opt'])`.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that tells if two checkboxes are checked.

Comment: yea, that was me trying to get the count from $_POST in the most ridiculous way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(count($_POST['opt']) >= 2)
{
    // at least 2 are checked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My example uses the opposite logic to the first person.

```
count_check = count($_POST['opt'])
if(count_check < 2)
{
  //stop submission
}
else
{
  //Proceed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<?php

if( is_array($_POST['opt']) )
{
    foreach($_POST['opt'] as $check)
        echo $check; 

    if(count($_POST['opt']) >= 2)
    {
         echo 'Valid';
    }
    else
    {
         echo 'Not valid';
    }

}
else
    echo 'Nothing checked';

?>
```